# Compiling MongoDB C++ driver on Cygwin

Tags: c++, mongodb, cygwin, nosql

I junt trying compile the MongoDB C++ driver on Cygwin with the 'scons' command and i getting this follow error:

```
src/mongo/db/nonce.cpp:48:20: error: ‘srandomdev’ was not declared in this scope
```

What lib is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The srandomdev function is available in **stdlib.h** on BSD or OSX systems, not on GNU systems like Cygwin or Linux.

It looks like the build script does not recognize the fact that you are running on Cygwin. There are a few options that you can try. The easiest ones are

### Change ifdef clause

Without a Windows machine to test this on, it is hard to confirm this will work for you.
In *src/mongo/platform/random.cpp* , edit line 108

```
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__sunos__) || defined(__APPLE__)
```

to be

```
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__sunos__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
```

### Delete the last else clause

Find the line (141 in my version) of *src/mongo/platform/random.cpp* that looks like

```
#else
class SRandSecureRandom : public SecureRandom {
public:
```

Delete the lines down to the `#endif` clause and then edit

```
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__sunos__) || defined(__APPLE__)
```

to simply be

```
#else
```

Comment: @GabrielBiga Since you did not accept this answer, can I assume it did not work?  Yet somebody up-voted it.  Is there a way to see who up-voted, and a way to contact them to see if it worked for them or if they just had a little premature optimism?