# Building MongoDB C++ Driver in Cygwin: generate_error_codes.py not found

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-c, mongo-c-driver

I am trying to build the MongoDB client library on Cygwin.

```
Administrator@dev /cygdrive/e/warez/dev-tools/cpp/mongodb-src-r2.4.8
$ scons mongoclient
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.3.0
python version: 2 7 5 'final' 0
No special config for [cygwin] which probably means it won't work
Checking whether the C++ compiler works(cached) yes
Checking for C header file unistd.h... (cached) yes
Checking whether clock_gettime is declared... (cached) yes
Checking for C library rt... (cached) yes
Checking for C++ header file execinfo.h... (cached) no
Checking for C library pcap... (cached) no
Checking for C library wpcap... (cached) no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: *** [build/cygwin/normal/mongo/base/error_codes.h] Source `src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py' not found, needed by target `build/cygwin/normal/mongo/base/error_codes.h'.
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Administrator@dev /cygdrive/e/warez/dev-tools/cpp/mongodb-src-r2.4.8
$ ls -l src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators None 8736 Oct 31 22:15 src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py
```

There are two questions related to building MongoDB driver:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060068/c-mongodb-driver-in-cygwin
- [Compiling MongoDB C++ driver on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185815/compiling-mongodb-c-driver-on-cygwin)

They didn't get the error:

> No special config for [cygwin] which probably means it won't work

I've tried both mongodb-src-r2.4.8 and latest code from github (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo), with no luck.

How should I fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if we support cygwin as built platform, i'll investigate.

Comment: At present, I'd recommend building the whole project and getting mongoclient built as part of it.

Comment: @Derick I'm looking forward to that...personally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running scons to build MongoDB under Cygwin bash on Windows is not currently supported.  The solution is to use a native Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: My working PC is Windows. Other components which depend on MongoDB Driver need to be built on Cygwin. Will the MongoDB C++ Driver built from Visual Studio work? (I'll try it out anyway...)